# How to detect key press in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Now it is able to **NSLog** the key event by this:

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event{
   NSLog(@"%hu",event.keyCode); 
}
```

But it won’t work if I switch it like this:

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event{
   NSLog(@"%hu",event.keyCode);
   switch(event.keyCode){
    case 0x0D:
        NSLog(@“pressed”);
}}
```

**Note:** I understand what is subclass.

Comment: how is the terminology _subclass_ related to this topic? can you elaborate it, please?

Comment: I tried your code and it works. Are you sure you're typing key code 0x0D?

Comment: Just don’t worry about subclass, when I researched about detecting key pressed it says you have to subclass first